# Arraylist doesn't get refilled and/or filtered

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filter, refresh

I have a list in angular, an array. OnInit it gets filled from the right corresponding database items. I created a form above it. When you enter something in the form, it acts like a filter. This works, the first time. When you erase something from the form and enter something else, the list should be refreshed and afterwards filtered based on the new input. This doesn't happen. I put the formula that happens on onInit in my function to refill the list.

Below you can find my function (I left the console logs in) and a screenshot of the problem. First I look for a user (joeri.boons@hi10.be) which returns three results. Than I erase the user and look based on a month 7. The screen returns a new unfilterd list while in the console it still holds the list of 3 x user joeri.boons@hi10.be. So there is an inconsistency to. If you look at screen result you would think of a filter problem, the console points at a refreshproblem.

if more code is required let me know.

```
  updateWithFilter(): void {
    console.log("function update filter reached")
       console.log(this.listadapted);
    if(this.listadapted == true){
     // this.timesheetsHandled = {} as TimeSheet[];
     this.getHandledSheet();
      console.log("getHandledSheet executed")
    }

    if(this.filterUsername.trim() && !this.filterYear && !this.filterMonth){
      console.log("option 1 reached")
      console.log(this.filterUsername.trim());
      console.log(this.filterYear);
      console.log(this.filterMonth);
          this.timesheetsHandled = this.timesheetsHandled.filter(sheet => sheet.username == this.filterUsername);
          this.listadapted = true;

    } else if(!this.filterUsername.trim() && !this.filterYear && this.filterMonth){
      console.log("option 2 reached");
      console.log(this.filterUsername.trim());
      console.log(this.filterYear);
      console.log(this.filterMonth);

      console.log("before filter");
      this.timesheetsHandled.forEach(sheet => console.log(sheet.username));
          this.timesheetsHandled = this.timesheetsHandled.filter(sheet => sheet.month == this.filterMonth);
          console.log("after filter");
          this.timesheetsHandled.forEach(sheet => console.log(sheet.username));
         // console.log(this.timesheetsHandled.filter(sheet => sheet.month == this.filterMonth));
          this.listadapted = true;

    } else if .. more options

}


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHandledSheet();
  }



  getHandledSheet(): void {
    this.timesheetService.getAllTimesheets().subscribe({next: (response: TimeSheet[]) => {this.timesheetsHandled = response.filter(sheet => sheet.status == 'HANDLED') }}) ;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that this is caused by loading data in ngOnInit. As the documentation (https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) states : [...] It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

I suspect that you create one instance and re-use it and the ngOnInit method does not get called again.

UPDATE:
The issue is that the call to  `this.getHandledSheet();` does a call to `.. .subscribe({next: ..` which is delayed and the rest of the function is executed first.
So the actual code after next: is only executed after the timeSheetService is done loading the data.

So either you apply the filter in the 
`{next: (response: TimeSheet[]) => {this.timesheetsHandled = response.filter(sheet => sheet.status == 'HANDLED') }}` 
block after filtering for 'HANDLED' or you'll try to await in the update function.

Comment: True, but I made a separate function, which I invoke on onInit, and that function is invoked again during updateFilterWith() .

Comment: You're right, that went over my head and as it looks it is executed correctly. Are you sure that the filter does not return the same set as the name? Just to be sure because month 7 might be 2022/08 due to index 0 for January?

Comment: Yes I am sure, when I only look for 7, it returns the right result. The first look up is always correct. It is the second one, without refreshing the page, that 'destroys' the  list

Comment: does...subscribe(next .. delay the actual loading until after the filtering code which still filters on the old list?

Comment: that might be the issue,.. So I need to use async await here to try if makes a difference. I will check!

Comment: If that was the case (which I strongly suspect) I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: using async await solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Create two variables, one that will always remain unfiltered, then another that will be filtered.

The problem will be that the original list is filtered, hence you are losing the original data after filtering!

```
timesheetHandled: TimeSheet[];
timesheetHandledOriginal: TimeSheet[];

updateWithFilter(): void {
    console.log('function update filter reached');
    console.log(this.listadapted);
    if (this.listadapted == true) {
        // this.timesheetsHandled = {} as TimeSheet[];
        this.getHandledSheet();
        console.log('getHandledSheet executed');
    }

    if (this.filterUsername.trim() && !this.filterYear && !this.filterMonth) {
        console.log('option 1 reached');
        console.log(this.filterUsername.trim());
        console.log(this.filterYear);
        console.log(this.filterMonth);
        this.timesheetsHandled = this.timesheetHandledOriginal.filter(
            sheet => sheet.username == this.filterUsername
        );
        this.listadapted = true;
    } else if (!this.filterUsername.trim() && !this.filterYear && this.filterMonth) {
        console.log('option 2 reached');
        console.log(this.filterUsername.trim());
        console.log(this.filterYear);
        console.log(this.filterMonth);

        console.log('before filter');
        this.timesheetsHandled.forEach(sheet => console.log(sheet.username));
        this.timesheetsHandled = this.timesheetHandledOriginal.filter(
            sheet => sheet.month == this.filterMonth
        );
        console.log('after filter');
        this.timesheetsHandled.forEach(sheet => console.log(sheet.username));
        // console.log(this.timesheetsHandled.filter(sheet => sheet.month == this.filterMonth));
        this.listadapted = true;
    }
    // else if .. more options
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHandledSheet();
}

getHandledSheet(): void {
    this.timesheetService.getAllTimesheets().subscribe({
        next: (response: TimeSheet[]) => {
            this.timesheetsHandled = response.filter(sheet => sheet.status == 'HANDLED');
            this.timesheetHandledOriginal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.timesheetsHandled));
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: But why doesn't the part in which I refresh the the list from the service with original data work as I think it would?

Comment: @YannickMussche I need more inputs, maybe a stackblitz with the issue replicated

Comment: @YannickMussche Its due to the list being empty, then the forEach will not run and hence you are not getting any output!

Comment: I''ll see what I can do, Creating a second list is not an option. The html needs to adapt to the list all the time.

Comment: @YannickMussche Could you try out this solution, it should fix your issue!

Comment: Sorry mate, I cannot make a second list. I know the first one is empty, I'm trying to get it filled again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247678/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-yannick-mussche).